# Align 2 paragrahs next to each other

Tags: html, alignment

I need to align 2 paragraphs side by side so that I can have all the information taking up less vertical space.

I need for one column to take up around 25% of the whole page's width, so that both columns take up around 50% of the page's width.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show your code and some effort. How it's done partly depends on how the rest of your document is structured.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flexbox` CSS modal to control the content flow

```css
.flex-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 50%;
}
.flex-wrapper .item {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
    <p class="flex-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem quia cumque aspernatur ut modi suscipit. Sunt natus reiciendis, quisquam enim iste facere incidunt voluptate voluptates amet, minus cupiditate molestiae provident.
    </p>
    <p class="flex-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem quia cumque aspernatur ut modi suscipit. Sunt natus reiciendis, quisquam enim iste facere incidunt voluptate voluptates amet, minus cupiditate molestiae provident.
    </p>
</div>
```